# vbs file search for extention in a directory

Tags: file, vbscript

I'm trying to write this code in VBs, (I'm quite new)
I want to have the code go through a folder/directory, and pick out all ".txt" files, in something like a for loop. These text files could then be listed using MsgBox ("txt filename"). This is what I've got so far:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\folder"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = ".txt" Then
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name

Next
```

It doesn't seem to be picking out a txt file called "name.txt". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ps:
please ignore and bad spelling and my terrible formatting (im new to stackoverflow) Thanks! (also the code above is mostly mashed together code i found off the internet)

Comment: You tell it to compare TXT with txt. That's what UCase means. `If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = LCase(".txt") Then`. I'm being a bit pedantic with the second LCase but that is how to compare text in vbscript is to samecase both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify this line ; if you use `UCase` :

```
If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = ".txt"
```

To

```
If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "TXT"
```

Or if you use `LCase`

```
If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "txt"
```

And your code looks like this one :

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\folder"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "txt" Then
        Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
    End If
Next
```

***[GetExtensionName Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0fxha2a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)***

Comment: potentially just use strcomp(, , vbTextCompare) to make it more obvious